# how to remove the content of the header file in the head element of the generated HTML files in dita ot

Tags: dita-ot

In DITA-OT when I'm publishing a dita file to *html5* in generated HTML page I got `<head>` element.

```xml
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="copyright" content="(C) Copyright 2020">
  <meta name="DC.rights.owner" content="(C) Copyright 2020">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonltr.css">
  <title>Paint</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

My requirement is I want to remove some content from the head element of the generated html5 output.

How can I remove the following snippet, for example?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonltr.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameters `dita-css` and `dita-bidi-css` or override the whole `generateCssLinks` template of the `topic.xsl`, see https://github.com/dita-ot/dita-ot/blob/develop/src/main/plugins/org.dita.html5/xsl/topic.xsl.

**Update**:
You have to override XSL-Stylesheets. To learn how to override them, you should read [Customizing HTML output](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/html-customization.html) and [Custom HTML plug-ins](https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/html-customization-plugins.html).

Comment: override generateCssLinks template means what? where we have to write the logic?can we create some xsl file or what? otherwise what parameter can set on dita-css and dita-bidi-css. can you explain me. plzzzz

Comment: I've updated the answer and added links referring to the docs. There you can find what you need to learn how to create custom HTML plugins.

Comment: I did override the generateCssLinks code. After what modification I need to changes I could not understand. here i got the error also <xsl:call-template name="getLowerCaseLang"/>.  So can u do this? plz help me out this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand you.